# cant display images in cakephp layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, cakephp

I am trying to get the images to display in my cakephp website. My task is simple to get the website labelled below 1) which is a cakephp website to look like the website labelled 2) which is a freeware website. The layout of website 1) has the cakephp code which just calls in a view for the middle'blue section'

I am getting the paths wrong to display images/js. I am not seeing what I doing wring with loading images and js

I load images like this

```
echo  $this->Html->image('f_pic2.jpg', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'`
```

I load Js like 2 ways an neither seem to have any effect.

```
  <?php
   echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery.min','jquery-ui.min','jquery.magnific-popup.js'));?>

<script src="web/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript">
```

// cant see images on website  1) that should appear from website 2). I have loaded all the files,images into the webroot img/js  dir

website cakephp 1) http://101.0.99.48/maths/users/calm
   website freeware 2) http://101.0.99.48/calm-pack/

I have read the docs and I dont know what I am doing wrong.

```
 http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html
   http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html
```

Comment: "_I am getting the paths wrong to display images/js_" What does that mean? What do the generated URLs look like? Where are your images located? How have you configured your asset paths? ... Questions should be self contained, and not link to external sources where one _may_ find contextual information!

Comment: I have already said how I am loading the images and they are stored in the webroot/img folder. You can see I have a few images to display but some do not for some unknown reason.I am not sure what information is missing. What is not clear from the information I have presented as I have given a lot. The links show what the issue is visually as well as being able to view source code generated.

Comment: For example why cant I display any of the images in the blue section using echo  $this->Html->image('pic2.jpg', array(...   given the images resides in the webroot/img folder?

Comment: Just saying that the files are stored in "_webroot img/js_" doesn't really suffice, as we don't know the resulting, public path structure. My main point was, that the information that can be gathered from the linked website should be _in your question_, as this is how StackOverflow is ment to work, questions should be self-contained and understandable even when possible external links do not work anymore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The original (missing?) answer is confusing as it mentions unnecessary file paths and it is a cakephp question as cakephp requires the css,js,image files to be referenced a certain way. Paths of files dont need to be included if placed in folders of the webroot folder. 
In each of the css files the reference to image paths also need to be changed

echo $this->Html->css(array('style')) ;
echo $this->Html->css(array('magnific-popup'));

echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery.min','jquery.easing.min','jquery.mixitup.min'));

Html->image('logo.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP')); ?>

the website now all works fine after these changes.  Previously the css file image paths were not set, js was included with paths and by a non cakephp way. Problem solved!

The finished product is here to prove this works
http://101.0.99.48/calm/users/calm

Comment: why has this question been voted down as a solution proving my point has been offered and a working website is the result? This is a good question